# Instrumentation class in the Android API

Tags: android, junit, instrumentation

I have question on the Android API. Android API provides a class called "Instrumentation" class. What is the use of this class? Is the Instrumentation class be used only together with Junit for unit testing.

Can Junit framework can be used to test the methods of the Android API without using the Instrumentation class.

Since Junit package has been included in the Android package, I hope we dont need to use install separately for unit testing.

I would appreciate if you could provide me the information as i can't find these clear information anywhere on the Web.

If we use Junit test framework to test the Android API, can we have test results in the UI format rather than test format.?

Thanks a lot. Apprecite your time.

Regards,
Riyas

Answer (score 4):

The Instrumentation class allows the test case to subscribe to various application events (keypresses, etc), and also programmatically control the UI to enable functional testing of your application.

Therefore, you technically do not need the Instrumentation class for Junit testing if all you are doing is unit testing, and not functional testing of the UI.  You **could** just extend [TestCase](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/junit/framework/TestCase.html) which does not provide any Instrumentation support.

Here is a [link](http://codinghard.wordpress.com/2009/06/04/a-first-look-at-the-android-testing-framework/) with some fairly good descriptions of the various test classes.

Junit is included within Android and will not need to be installed separately.

Answer (score 0):

Instrumentation API is basically used to inject various kinds of events to the UI so that the application can be stress-tested. You can create an arbitrary event like tapping on the screen and inject it using instrumentation API which is basically like a pseudo event generation.

Answer (score 0):

Instrumentation class is a base class for test frameworks, this provides a very specific functionality, It also provides API to invoke test on device/emulator using ActivityManager Interface via ADB. Also, it can gets back the results to the development machines.

By overriding this class you can enjoy all the context and helper classes you need to run your tests.

Below is a sample implementation, I wrote to explain you the functionality.

```
public class SampleInstrumentation extends Instrumentation {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
        super.onCreate(arguments);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("whatisthis","thisiswhat");
        finish(0,bundle);

    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
...
...
    </application>
    <instrumentation
        android:name=".SampleInstrumentation"
        android:targetPackage="com.commons"></instrumentation>
</manifest>
```

Now if you run this command from your development machine.

```
adb shell am instrument -w -m com.commons/com.commons.SampleInstrumentation
```

Your instrumentation class onCreate methods get called and you will get some binary encoded response on your console containing data from the bundle you passed to the 'finish' function.

```
"


whatisthis
thisiswhat
```

I hope this will make you understand the functionality specific to this base class. For the sake of some motivation, I would like to add that the new android testing framework `androidx.test` gets compiled with our app (not part of OS and can be modified) directly extends the Instrumentation class (part of Android Framework/OS implementation). Hence you can write your own implementation of a whole new testing framework just by using this class.